# JB sms test not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

I have a JB using SMS, with a DE that is sendable/testable and includes a subscriber key. See image to see how data is setup.

[image: Sample of data format]The journey validates fine, allows me to select testers from the DB, but when the test runs, no one receives the test. How do I fix it?

Comment: are you using test mode or activating the journey to test?

Comment: Are you opting the testers in to a keyword in the Send SMS Activity or only sending to those already opted in?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Journey Builder's test mode, no one will receive any messages. This is the desired and documented outcome:

> Then launch a simulated journey and watch each contact’s path through the journey—without sending messages to those contacts.
> (Source: [Journey Testing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_testing.htm&type=5))

The purpose of the test mode is to see if your contacts go through the desired path in your journey without having to activate the journey, waiting at wait-activities and having messages sent out.
For data extension entry events there is an alternative test mode that - at least for email messages - lets you define one recipient email address for all messages sent. As far as I know there is no such option for SMS messages.

In order to receive the messages you need to activate the journey like you would for the GoLive of your journey. However, if you do so for testing purposes, you need to make sure only your desired test contacts enter the journey! This can be done either by filtering them out in the entry event and/or adding a decision split as first activity. In that decision split you need to check for the SubscriberKey, PhoneNumber or something similar that identifies your test contacts.

**Related documentation:**

- [Journey Testing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_testing.htm&type=5)
- [Test Your Journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_test_your_journey.htm&type=5)
- [Use Decision Splits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_decision_splits.htm&type=5)